# How to prevent textures moving around tentacles created with geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

So, I recreated this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tlXEqfXMQLo&t=4s) but animated the tentacles.

[image]
It works nicely, but the textures are moving around during animation because there are no UV maps. I tried Capture Attributes of the curves with Combine XYZ and the attribute node in the shader but the UVs or textures are all messed up (just long lines and weird patterns). I found another tip on this site that uses Transfer Attributes of geometry but this also didn't work.
Here's a little [test scene of my setup](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6jic4x1wkitu47g/testscene.blend?dl=0)
Is there a way to get nice bump maps that stick to the moving tentacles? :)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really have anything to do with your Geometry nodes setup, it's all to do with your materials.

Right now you don't have a mapping node setup and the noise that's driving the bump is using Generated UV coordinates.

[image]

In any case however, There's not gonna be any good way to add a bump map to these tentacles procedurally without converting them into meshes and uv unwrapping them. Every other option is gonna have some downside (stretching, not moving etc.)

Comment: Thank you, I deleted the mapping because it doesn't make a difference. Too bad it isn't working within geometry nodes...

Comment: That's just the nature of procedural geometry, you can use it get infinite variation but once you need it to be something production ready, you'll need to *Realize Instances* and *Convert to Mesh* to actually UV Unwrap the ones you like.